# Description of $PSL_n$-torsors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

It is a classical result that $PGL_n$-torsors over a field $K$ correspond to central simple algebras of degree $n$ over $K$.

I was wondering if there is a similar description for $PSL_n$-torsors along similar lines. What about other projectivizations of classical groups?

A reference would be useful, unfortunately I could not find anything on my own.

Comment: What are the differences, to you, of PGL_n and PSL_n?

Comment: If you want a reference to both questions, try ``The book of involutions" by Knus, Merkurjev, Rost, Tignol. Chapter 7 in particular contains, most likely, exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes in that chapter there are so many of those, but $PSL_n$ is missing. So I thought that maybe there's a reason for that, this is why I asked here.